# ¿Como pasar un list de assets a un list de files en flutter?

Tags: android, imagen, flutter

Estoy usan la libreria multi_image_picker: ^4.6.0 para cargar varias imagenes desde el dispositivo, estas imagenes crean list asset con el metodo siguiente:

```
List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();

String _error = 'No error detected';

Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    String error = 'Error no detected';

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 7,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Example App",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
      _error = error;
    });
  }
```

Los asset de las imagenes que cargo se guardan en resultList y ese resultList lo uso para guardarlos en otra lista de assets llamadas images, este list llamado images lo uso para llenar el siguiente GridView.

```
//Botón para cargar las imagenes
                FlatButton.icon(
                  label: Text('Seleccionar fotos'),
                  onPressed: loadAssets,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                ),

                //Vista para mostrar las imagenes cargadas
                GridView.count(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
                    Asset asset = images[index];
                    identifiers += images[index].identifier.toString()+"\n";
                    return AssetThumb(
                      asset: asset,
                      height: 300,
                      width: 300,
                    );
                  }),
                ),
```

Como pueden observar trato de guardar el identifier en una cadena debido a que en un principio crei que en ese identifier podia obtener el path de la imagen y pasarla a un String que guardo en sqlite, pero los elementos del list images son solo assets, quisiera saber si se obtener el path de la imagen a partir del asset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisas el archivo `asset.dart` del plugin : https://github.com/Sh1d0w/multi_image_picker/blob/master/lib/src/asset.dart

Puedes observar que tiene un método `getByteData` donde puedes obtener el `ByteData` de cada imagen.

Aquí te pongo un método con el que puedes guardarlo en un archivo:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


Future<File> writeToFile(ByteData data) async {
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var filePath = tempPath + '/nombre.png'; 
    return File(filePath).writeAsBytes(
        buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
}
```

Vas a tener que usar el package `path_provider` y recorrer tu `resultList` para obtener cada `File`.

//Ejemplo solo de un asset

```dart
Asset primero = resultList.first;
File primerFile = await writeToFile(await primero.getByteData());
```

Comment: cuando intento implementar tu solución me genera la siguiente excepción:

The argument type 'Future<ByteData>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ByteData'.

Comment: Corregido, me faltaba el await adelante de primero.getByteData